# PL/SQL How to get X day ago from a Date as Date?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get 100 days ago from 08-APR-13, as date.

How to do it with pl/sql?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assumption was made that the `08-APR-13` is a string in your situation. So you need convert it to `date` using `to_date` function, and then simply subtract 100 literal.

- SQL

  ```
  SQL> select (to_date('08-APR-13', 'DD-MON-RR') - 100) res
    2    from dual
    3  /

  RES
  -----------
  29-12-2012
  ```
- PL/SQL

  ```
  SQL> declare
    2    l_res_date date;
    3    l_in_date  varchar2(11) := '08-APR-13';
    4  begin
    5    select (to_date(l_in_date, 'DD-MON-RR') - 100)
    6      into l_res_date
    7    from dual;
    8  
    9    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_res_date, 'dd-mon-yy'));
    10  end;
    11  /

    29-dec-12

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
  ```

OR

```
     SQL> declare
       2    l_res_date date;
       3    l_in_date  varchar2(11) := '08-APR-13';
       4  begin
       5  
       6    l_res_date := to_date(l_in_date, 'DD-MON-RR') - 100;
       7  
       8    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_res_date, 'dd-mon-yy'));
       9  end;
       10  /

       29-dec-12

       PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 2):

this can be done select query by just minus as Nicholas Krasnov said..
IN pl/sql  by creating a function DATE_AGO whose input parameter is date and number of days you need to subtract...

```
    create or replace function DATE_AGO(DATE1  date, NUMBER_DAYS number)  return date
    is
      V_DATE1 date:=DATE1;
      v_NUMBER_DAYS number:=NUMBER_DAYS;
    begin
      V_DATE1:=V_DATE1-v_NUMBER_DAYS;
      return V_DATE1;
    when OTHERS then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE);
    end DATE_AGO;
    /
    SHOW ERRORS;


select DATE_AGO('08-APR-13',100) from DUAL;
```