# Subtracting Number of Days from a Date in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to subtract a given x number of days from sysdate, can someone assist me on how to do that, I am using the PL/SQL language. THANKS!

Comment: I think [this answers it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13509177/1911388).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use sysdate-1 to subtract one day from system date.

```
select sysdate, sysdate -1 from dual;
```

Output:

```
SYSDATE  SYSDATE-1
-------- ---------
22-10-13 21-10-13
```

Comment: I prefer "select (sysdate - interval '1' day) from dual" With the plain "sysdate-1" it get's more complicated in the case of hours, weeks etc. but with this approach it comes along

Answer (score 8):

simply,

```
select sysdate-1 from dual
```

there's a bunch more info and detail here: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_add_a_day_hour_minute_second_to_a_date_value