# Extracting records from the last 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How can I extract only the records of the *last* 30 days in a manner that it is automatically updated whenever I run the query?

I'm using Oracle

Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting Number of Days from a Date in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523019/subtracting-number-of-days-from-a-date-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following ---

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE DATECOLUMN >= SYSDATE - 30;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Table.ColumnName >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```